# Use Case in procedure using mssql2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SortModules
@flag int
AS 
BEGIN
    CASE @flag  
        WHEN  0 THEN SELECT FriendlyName,ModuleID FROM [dbo].[Modules] order by FriendlyName asc
        WHEN  1 THEN SELECT FriendlyName,ModuleID FROM [dbo].[Modules] order by FriendlyName desc
    END
END<
```

in a above procedure i got an error
.`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.`
`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.`
`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.`.
Plz help to find my mistake.Thanks

Comment: @Mitch Wheat plz suggest the correct way.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT FriendlyName,ModuleID
FROM [dbo].[Modules]
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @flag = 0 THEN FriendlyName END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @flag = 1 THEN FriendlyName END DESC
```

Comment: Presumably this will negate any possibility of using an index on `FriendlyName,ModuleID` to avoid a sort?

Comment: @Martin Smith: TBH, never tested it. I try to avoid CASE like this in ORDER BYs and use separate statements (like you) or ROW_NUMBER solutions

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use an `IF` statement rather than a `CASE` statement here.

```
IF @flag = 0 
BEGIN
    SELECT FriendlyName,ModuleID FROM [dbo].[Modules] order by FriendlyName
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT FriendlyName,ModuleID FROM [dbo].[Modules] order by FriendlyName DESC 
END
```

More information on [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).